# Create a new list from given data

Tags: list-manipulation, data, dataset

Let us consider the following type of data list

```
data = {{0.35, 0.2}, {-0.0700506}, {-1.04149}, {0.52, 0.2}, {-0.0100506}, {-1.02149}, {0.593423},
        {0.75, 0.2}, {0.0700506}, {1.04149}, {-0.193423}, {-0.834902}}
```

We see that first, we have a sub-list guide with two elements {a, b}, then we have single elements {c} and then new sub-list guides.

I want the following: create a new list containing the first element of each guide sub-list along with all the following single elements. In our case, we should have the following output

```
data2 = {{0.35, -0.0700506}, {0.35, -1.04149}, {0.52, -0.0100506}, {0.52, -1.02149}, 
         {0.52, 0.593423}, {0.75, 0.0700506}, {0.75, 1.04149}, {0.75, -0.193423}, {0.75, -0.834902}}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the second element of `{a, b}` always going to be 0.2, or at least the same across al sublists?

Comment: @MarcoB No, it won't be always the same, but we do not care about the second element..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SequenceCases[data, {a : {_, _}, b : {_} ..} :>
    (Sequence @@ ({a[[1]], #} & /@ Flatten[{b}]))]
```

> ```
> {{0.35, -0.0700506}, {0.35, -1.04149}, {0.52, -0.0100506},
>  {0.52, -1.02149}, {0.52, 0.593423}, {0.75, 0.0700506},
>  {0.75, 1.04149}, {0.75, -0.193423}, {0.75, -0.834902}}
> ```

Alternatively, `Split` and post-process:

```
Join @@ Map[Thread[{First @ #, Rest @ #}] &] @ 
   Split[data, Length[#2] == 1 &][[All, All, 1]]
```

> ```
>  same result
> ```

Comment: It works well! Just a comment: in cases where the original data list contains too many elements, the procedure of obtaining the new list is very time-consuming (several minutes of CPU time). Is there a way to speed us the process?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, the updated version of the second method is slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
data =
  {{0.35, 0.2}, {-0.0700506}, {-1.04149},
   {0.52, 0.2}, {-0.0100506}, {-1.02149}, {0.593423},
   {0.75, 0.2}, {0.0700506}, {1.04149}, {-0.193423}, {-0.834902}};

Catenate @ ReplaceAll[{{a_, _}, b__} :> Prepend[a] /@ {b}] @
   Split[data, Length[#2] == 1 &] // Column
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
data =
  {{0.35, 0.2}, {-0.0700506}, {-1.04149},
   {0.52, 0.2}, {-0.0100506}, {-1.02149}, {0.593423},
   {0.75, 0.2}, {0.0700506}, {1.04149}, {-0.193423}, {-0.834902}};
```

A variant of @eldo's answer using `Split`:

```
pattern = {a : {_, _}, b : {_} ..} :> Splice@Tuples[{{a[[1]]}, Flatten[{b}]}];

ReplaceAll[pattern]@Split[data, Length[#2] == 1 &] // Column
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{0.35, 0.2}, {-0.0700506}, {-1.04149}, {0.52, 
    0.2}, {-0.0100506}, {-1.02149}, {0.593423}, {0.75, 
    0.2}, {0.0700506}, {1.04149}, {-0.193423}, {-0.834902}};

Split[data, Length@#2 == 1 &] // 
  Map[Thread[{First@First@#, Sequence @@@ Rest@#}] &] // 
 Flatten[#, 1] &
```

---

*Result:*

> {{0.35, -0.0700506}, {0.35, -1.04149}, {0.52, -0.0100506}, {0.52, 
> -1.02149}, {0.52, 0.593423}, {0.75, 0.0700506}, {0.75,
> 1.04149}, {0.75, -0.193423}, {0.75, -0.834902}}