# Select elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, data

Suppose we have the following data list

```
data = {{-1, 2}, {0, 3}, {6, 6}, {1}, {-5, 1}, {0, 0}, {3}, {-3, 3}, {1, 2}, {1}, 
        {0, -1}, {2, 2}, {7}, {5, 5}, {2, 2}, {3, -3}, {4, -4}, {2, -2}, {7}}
```

The data are formatted as follows: first, we have N rows of (a,b) elements and then a row with a single element c which determines the end and the class of the (a,b) sub-list.
My question: how can I choose all the (a,b) elements for a given value of c?

For example, in the above list choose all elements for which c = 1 and create `data2` as

```
data2 = {{-1, 2}, {0, 3}, {6, 6}, {-3, 3}, {1, 2}}
```

Comment: `Split[data, ! MatchQ[#1, {_}] &] // Cases[#, {x___, {1}} :> x] &` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is inspired from the answer given by [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) in your other [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/243902/create-a-new-list-from-given-data):

```
data = {{-1, 2}, {0, 3}, {6, 6}, {1}, {-5, 1}, {0, 0}, {3}, {-3, 
    3}, {1, 2}, {1}, {0, -1}, {2, 2}, {7}, {5, 5}, {2, 
    2}, {3, -3}, {4, -4}, {2, -2}, {7}};
```

First split them:

```
SequenceCases[data, {a : {_, _} .., {b_}} :> b -> Sequence[a]]

(*Out: {1 -> Sequence[{-1, 2}, {0, 3}, {6, 6}], 
 3 -> Sequence[{-5, 1}, {0, 0}],
 1 -> Sequence[{-3, 3}, {1, 2}], 
 7 -> Sequence[{0, -1}, {2, 2}], 
 7 -> Sequence[{5, 5}, {2, 2}, {3, -3}, {4, -4}, {2, -2}]}*)
```

Then apply `Merge` to merge duplicate keys:

```
result = Merge[
  SequenceCases[data, {a : {_, _} .., {b_}} :> b -> Sequence[a]], 
  Identity]

(*Out: <|1 -> {{-1, 2}, {0, 3}, {6, 6}, {-3, 3}, {1, 2}}, 
 3 -> {{-5, 1}, {0, 0}}, 
 7 -> {{0, -1}, {2, 2}, {5, 5}, {2, 2}, {3, -3}, {4, -4}, {2, -2}}|>*)
```

Just give your value `c` as key to the result:

```
result[1]

(*Out: {{-1, 2}, {0, 3}, {6, 6}, {-3, 3}, {1, 2}} *)

result[7]

(*Out: {{0, -1}, {2, 2}, {5, 5}, {2, 2}, {3, -3}, {4, -4}, {2, -2}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
split = Split[data, Length @ # != 1 &];

Column @ split
```

[image]

You can use `GroupBy` to get an `Association` with singleton elements in `data` used as keys:

```
grouped = GroupBy[split, First @* Last -> Most]
```

> ```
> <|1 -> {{{-1, 2}, {0, 3}, {6, 6}}, {{-3, 3}, {1, 2}}}, 
>   3 -> {{{-5, 1}, {0, 0}}}, 
>   7 -> {{{0, -1}, {2, 2}}, {{5, 5}, {2, 2}, {3, -3}, {4, -4}, {2, -2}}}|>
> ```

You can `Query` `grouped`:

```
grouped @ 1
```

> ```
>  {{{-1, 2}, {0, 3}, {6, 6}}, {{-3, 3}, {1, 2}}}
> ```

and extract desired `Part`s:

```
First @ grouped @1
```

> ```
> {{-1, 2}, {0, 3}, {6, 6}}
> ```

or use `Part` directly:

```
grouped[[1, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{-1, 2}, {0, 3}, {6, 6}}
> ```

Comment: Or `GroupBy[split, First@*Last -> Most, Apply[Join]]`